# If I forfeit Breaking News, will the tags stick?

Tags: android-netrunner

[Breaking News](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/breaking-news-core) is an agenda that reads:

> When you score Breaking News, give the Runner 2 tags.
>
> When the turn on which you scored Breaking News ends, the Runner loses 2 tags.

**If I find some way of forfeiting it during the turn I score it, does the second "clause" fail to fire, so the Runner keeps the tags?**

The reason I think it's ambiguous is because the two effects are listed as separate paragraphs, with separate "when" statements, suggesting they may trigger separately, rather than being both-or-neither. If the card is no longer in play because it's been forfeited, the card text no longer has an effect on the game. (Compare a card like [Joshua B](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/genesis/cyber-exodus/joshua-b-cyber-exodus), which has a "when this turn ends" effect as PART of the main effect, suggesting it would have already triggered regardless of whether the card remains in play or not.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the latest [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/2013-February/Netrunner%20LCG%20FAQ%201.1%20Printer%20Friendly.pdf) from FFG the case of Archer, Amazon Industrial Zone and Breaking News is mentioned.

> If the Corp scores
>   Breaking News
>   and then rezzes
>   Archer
>   through a card effect, forfeiting the Breaking News, does the
>   Runner keep the 2 tags?
>
> **Yes**. The conditional ability on Breaking News has not yet
>   triggered, and it will not trigger when the turn ends since the
>   card is no longer active.

So yes, the tags stick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought I looked in the FAQ, but it must not have been the latest. As a follow-up, am I right in thinking that the same does not apply to Joshua B? That is, if I use its ability, but trash it somehow during my turn (e.g. with Aesop's Pawnshop), the "when your turn ends" effect still occurs, because the effect is already triggered BEFORE the end of turn?

Comment: Yes, Joshua B triggers a "gain a click, gain a tag at the end of your turn" ability, while Breaking News has 2 separate abilities. This means you can't cheat a click out of Joshua B without getting the tag, unless you use Decoy.